# How to add plugins to website from GitHub?

Tags: javascript, jquery, git, codepen

I'm looking to add some plugins, [CircleType.js](http://circletype.labwire.ca/) and [Lettering.js](http://letteringjs.com/) specifically, to a CodePen project and I'm not sure how to proceed.

I've come across this before situation before, where I find a great plugin to use, and the installation is simply documented as "download from GitHub". Then the repo on GitHub is missing the actual steps to install. I've tried Googling this, but search results are always something not related, such as installing Wordpress plugins.

There must be some standard way to install plugins to websites, I just can't seem to find any help on adding a plugin from GitHub to a website or CodePen project.

Any help would be deeply appreciated. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can request the files as text from `raw.githubusercontent.com` available at `Raw` option at the repositories

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/peterhry/CircleType/master/js/circletype.js

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davatron5000/Lettering.js/master/jquery.lettering.js

then create `<script>` elements, set `.textContent` of `<script>` element to text response, append the `script` to `document`.

```
fetch("/path/to/raw/file")
.then(response => response.text())
.then(text => {
  let script = document.createElement("script");
  script.textContent = text;
  document.body.appendChild(script);
  script.onload = () => {
    // do stuff with object defined in script
  }
})
```

Comment: I don't that worked for me. I tried a console.log in the onload part, nothing shows up. I also tried loading both plugins then try one of them out, still nothing.

Comment: Can you create a stacksnippets of plnkr https://plnkr.co to demonstrate? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve